# Accessing correct overloaded virtual function

Tags: c++, function, overriding, virtual

I am trying to override the `virtual void clear();` below:

```
class DerivatedGraphicsContext : public osg::GraphicsContext {
public:
    void clear() { /* Do something */ }
};
```

However, I need initialize my `DerivatedGraphicsContext` object using the `osg::GraphicsContext::createGraphicsContext` method:

```
DerivatedGraphicsContext* dgc = (DerivatedGraphicsContext*)osg::GraphicsContext::createGraphicsContext(..);
```

The problem is that when I now call `dgc->clear();` it will call the osg::GraphicsContext::clear() method.

I have tried casting `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` but I am not really sure if it is possible, or if I need to re-implement the createGraphicsContext in my derived class in order for the `clear()` method to be accessed by the `DerivatedGraphicsContext` class.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Edit:

`createGraphicsContext(..)` returns `osg::GraphicsContext*` which it gets created by calling some windows API.

Because osg::GraphicsContext has pure virtual functions, the class is abstract and cannot be instantiated without implementing the methods. Thus, it is not even possible to use the `osg::GraphicsContext* gc = new osg::GraphicsContext()`, and of course the same goes for the `DerivatedGraphicsContext` as well.

Since I cannot use the new keyword I am not able to copy its contents to a `DerivatedGraphicsContext` of which I could have returned its pointer.

The source is available here:

source: http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//browser/OpenSceneGraph/trunk/src/osg/GraphicsContext.cpp

header: http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//browser/OpenSceneGraph/trunk/include/osg/GraphicsContext

Comment: You need to confirm two things. 1) Is the function signatures the same and 2) Is the clear() function marked as virtual in osg::GraphicsContext

Comment: Try `... = &dynamic_cast<DerivatedGraphicsContext&>(*osg::GraphicsContext::createGraphicsContext(..));` and tell us the results

Comment: And a third thing:  `createGraphicsContext()` really creates  a DerivativedGraphicContext ?  Because casting the objet pointer wont change the virtual functions the object obtained at construction...

Comment: Yes, the clear() function is virtual in osg::GraphicsContext, both have return type void without any arguments.

The: `... = &dynamic_cast<DerivatedGraphicsContext&>(*osg::GraphicsContext::createGraphicsCo‌​ntext(..));` causes a std::bad_cast exception.

The `createGraphicsContext()` returns a `osg::GraphicsContext*`, that is why I am doing the casting.

Comment: If the virtual functions are decided at the time of object creation, I suppose it should be possible to create a new `DerivatedGraphicsContext` and then copy the data from the `osg::GraphicsContext`, something similar to the idea of @JohannesSchaub-litb

Comment: The issue is that if I try to use `new DerivatedGraphicsContext()` I get the `cannot instantiate abstract class` error, and if avoidable I would rather implement only the virutal functions that I want to change rather than all of the ones  present in `osg::GraphicsContext`

Answer (score 0):

Possibility of casting result of createGraphicsContext(..) call to DerivatedGraphicsContext* obviously depends on object that is actually created in createGraphicsContext, and its class. As you state that clear() method is declated at base class osg::GraphicsContext as virtual, I suppose that the real runtime type of createGraphicsContext return value is nothing to do with DerivatedGraphicsContext. And if it's true, dynamic_casting to DerivatedGraphicsContext* will just give you NULL value. I think you need to implement another static factory method in your descendant class, similar to GraphicsContext::createGraphicsContext, or use [Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern for purpose of selecting class to instantiate.

Comment: Wouldn't the factory method aim to create a new DerivatedGraphicsContext? When I would want to use the pointer to the osg::GraphicsContext* from the createGraphicsContext method?

Comment: Yes, you should create new factory method to create object of DerivatedGraphicsContext class. In the C++ language runtime type of an object can not be changed during the lifetime of that object. Already created GraphicsContext instance can't became DerivatedGraphicsContext instance. So, in your factory method you can use some data from existing GraphicsContext object to create a brand new DerivatedGraphicsContext object.

Comment: From what I understood by reading about the Factory method, is that I need to use the new keyword in order to create an object of the DerivatedGraphicsContext, which is not possible since it is an abstract class due to its pure virtual functions